# Serializing OpenXML Parts Elements Storing in VARBINARY SQL 2005

Tags: xml-serialization, openxml-sdk, varbinary

I am building a solution that allows users to pick and chose sections from a Word template, populate those sections with content from a database, and assemble the 1k
new data into a new .docx document
So far, I have successful methodologies for locating content and transplanting that content into a new document.  I am using the OpenXML SDK 2.0 to locate content by Styles and Content Controls. I am able to create IEnumerable objects containing elements such as Paragraphs, SdtBlocks, Run, etc.

I need to find an elegant way to serialize these element blocks so I can store them as whole blocks of type VARBINARY in a SQL 2005 database. Can someone please point me to a viable example for serializing these OpenXML parts/elements?

Comment: Why VARBINARY?? Why not store those chunks of XML in a column of type XML ??

Comment: You're correct on the data type. I hadn't noticed the XML type.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Excel at the moment but I think your problem is similar in nature.

From the code below I can extract the XML code of the row and then store it.

```
private string GetContents(uint rowIndex)
{
    return GetExistingRow(rowIndex).OuterXml;
}

private Row GetExistingRow(uint rowIndex)
{
    return SheetData.
            Elements<Row>().
            Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).
            FirstOrDefault();
}
```

please note the SheetData object is extracted as

```
this.SheetData = WorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>()
```

I hope this helps.